# How to detect the completion of HTTP request in angular1

Tags: angularjs, http

is there any possibility to detect the completion of HTTP request in angular1 ?

product factory :

```
app
  .factory('productFactory', ['$http','config',
    function($http,config) {
      var url = config.domainBase +':'+config.domainPort +config.additionalPath+'/Product/All'
      return {
        getAll: function() {
          return $http.get(url);
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

Product Controller :

```
var req = productFactory.getAllServers();
            req.success(function(response) {
//....
}).
error(function(error){
//error
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at $q injector

```js
var deferred = $q.defer();
var params = {
  ...
};
$http.post('http://www.example.com', JSON.stringify(params))
  .success(function(object) {
    // On success
  })
  .error(function(object, status) {
    // On error
  });
return deferred.promise;
```